# proper way to send mailers using php?

Tags: php, email

I have php script to send 1,00,000 mails everyday.. 
it just runs all emails in loop and invoke mail() function..

I can't use mailinglist manager because. each mail has different content, unique clickurls.
is it the proper way to send mailers?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending thousands of emails from a PHP script is a bit messy at best. One of the real problems is to ensure that the script keeps running as long as necessary to do the job. You can do that if you keep resetting the time out for PHP and you have permission to do that, but there's still going to be a host of other problems.

The best thing to do is to build the email message and the list of recipients in PHP then hand the task of mailing off to something else - either a shell script or some kind of application that gets spawned off and detached from PHP in some way.

Also have you tried using SwiftMailer etc?

Answer (score 2):

It should be alright, as long as you provide users a link to unsubscribe from the mailing list. Make sure you're on good terms with your SMTP server provider. Otherwise, the server will get blacklisted.

**EDIT:** Many SMTP servers have limitations on the number of emails you can send out in an hour. Find out this limit for your SMTP server and put a small delay() in your loop after sending out each email.

Answer (score -2):

php mail(...) function?